Order of the pole at $z=0$, of $f(z)=\frac1{z(e^z-1)}$
Find the order of the pole  at the singularity
$z =0$,  of  $$f(z)=\frac1{z(e^z-1)}.$$
I have tried solving this question through expansion of exponential z
but the I got stuck in next steps .
The answer provided to this ques was order = 3 and I can't get it how they got this as answer .
Please help me .

The order is $2$, not $3$.
